# Data miss match in citusDB with jdbc driver

Tags: postgresql, citus

i am try to insert data into **citusDB** using same code as **postgresql** (**java JDBC connection**). Insertion get success and display all the values in my select query(in java code). But i can't able to list that rows in citusDB postgresql console. And the same happen when insert in citusDB postgresql console (insertion get success and values listed in console, but values are not list using java code).

Comment: Are you sure they're both connecting to the same database? Maybe you also have postgres running on your machine, or your citus instance has multiple databases?